# Get value from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the column `Position` **for each selected rows and add it in a list** with id `items`.

I managed to get how many rows are selected but not the actual value. Can anyone help me with this?

**PS: you have to click in the row**

Example: If I select first and second row I should get a list with `Accountant` and `System Architect`

**Working Code, you can edit it.**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var events = $('#events');
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    select: true,
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Get selected data',
      action: function () {
        var count = table.rows({selected: true}).count();
        events.prepend( '<div>'+count+' row(s) selected</div>');
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
#events {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.4/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="events">
  Row selected count - new information added at the top
</div>

<ul id="items"></ul>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: anyone? please :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation and attach a click handler on the  element. to get the position of the `<tr>` you can use the **[index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)** jQuery function and to get the text you can use the jQuery **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** function , try you the below code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'table tr > td', function() {
    console.log($(this).parent().index() + ' ' + $(this).index()); // Will console.log the parent() index and also the index of the <tr> clicked on.
    $('ul#items').append('<li>' + $.trim($(this).text()) + '</li>');
    return false;
});
```